# Django 2.0 - Add admin template to regular view

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to add the template of the Django Administration to a simple app view with staff member permissions. I've added `{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}` at the top of my view, but some parts of the header are missing.

**Normal admin header:**

[image]

**Test view with admin template:**

[image]

**my_app/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', views.test, name='test')
]
```

**my_app/views.py:**

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@staff_member_required
def test(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

**my_app/templates/test.html:**

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>Test</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**my_project/urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
admin.autodiscover()

admin.site.site_header = "Test 1"
admin.site.index_title = "Test 2"
admin.site.site_title = "Test 3"

urlpatterns = [
    path('my_app/', include('my_proj.my_app.urls')),
    path('', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Thank you!